# Getting specific object from Struts List

Tags: ajax, struts2

In my view page, I have

```
 <s:if test="%{!assignedProductBean.roleList.isEmpty()}">
  <s:select theme="simple" name="roleCode" id="selectRole"
    cssStyle="width:118px;" list="assignedProductBean.roleList"
    listKey="roleCode" listValue="roleCode" headerKey=""
    headerValue="--Select--" onchange="javascript:showRoleCharDiv()" />
 </s:if>
```

in showRoleCharDiv I have some code which fetches the data from selected role from roleList arrayList.

How can I know which object is selected so that I can directly display the respective role object other properties without hitting Action.

One more doubt, is it possible to get any jsp page using Ajax without actually hitting Action class in struts. I have every data needed in my bean, but without hitting action class, I need to replace div element with another jsp.

Comment: what you mean by `which object is selected`? do you mean the selected value of your select

Comment: yes. based on that value, I need to get that object from the list

Comment: have you tried `showRoleCharDiv(this.value)`

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi, Sorry i didn't get you. How can I call showRoleCharDiv(this.value)? the showRoleCharDiv is div element (div id="showRoleCharDiv")

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have all the data from your bean in the first action call, that data is not stored unless you evaluate and print it in the `showRoleCharDiv` of JSP.  If you didn't want to make a call to an Action again, then you would have to load all the objects into the JSP the first time around and hide it from the view with CSS.  You can use javascript to then unhide the selected object's data.

But I wouldn't recommend going this route.

You can use Ajax to replace the div element with another jsp but this would require a call to an Action class again.

Comment: isn't it a backdrop of Struts? May be My Bean is having lot of properties, depending upon situation, I may use only few of them and unless I use all of them, unable to regain them is certainly issue in my view